# How to check if the user is logged in on any website

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am creating a widget that can be added through a script tag to any website. I am planning to display it conditonally, based on wether or not the user is logged in.

How can I check if a user is logged in - on any website ? I know I need to check the cookies, but I doubt there is a universal cookie name that stores the login information for all websites.

How should I go about this ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should specify who the user is. Is it the random visitor (THEIR user) or is it the owner of the website (YOUR user)? Also, who is logged into where? Logged into YOUR website or logged into THEIR website?

Comment: @Ozone Thanks for the reply!  It is a random visitor (the website's user). For example eggcartons.com adds my script tag. Whenever a user is logged in on eggcartons.com I do not display my widget.

Comment: There's no generic way to check if a visitor is logged into any site, you have to be able to either access the sites internal login state or else you'd have to agree with your vendors that they provide your api with a boolean of some sort. It's going to be customization hell. Also, big chance that the scripts from your domain will be blocked by visitor browser anyway.

Comment: @Ozone Why would they be blocked if the site's owner adds the script tag in the head ? Check out this localizejs script tag : https://help.localizejs.com/docs/quickstart-for-web#integration-instructions.

Comment: There is no universal thing for being logged in....

Comment: What is your actual goal? What does being logged in differ with your embeded script?

Comment: @epascarello I am trying to conditionally display a survey if the user is not logged in

Answer (score 0):

The person who embeds your script should pass a state to it, if it is logged in or not.

Comment: I think this would add an extra layer of friction when adding the script tag. Is there any other way to achieve this ?